# find/sort multiple values from multidimensional array using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, array-filter, array-push

I'd like to sort an array such that i can extract some users from a multidimensional array based on one parameter, their email addresses. Ultimately I'd like to have the original array separated as 2 different arrays: one with chose email address (labeled `$js` below) and one's not (labeled `$not_js` below).

Here's my my code:

```
<?php
$users['1'] = array('name'=>'bob barker',
               'email'=>'bb@bb.com',
                  'id'=>'1');

$users['2'] = array('name'=>'jerry jones',
               'email'=> 'jj@jj.com',
                  'id'=>'2' );

$users['3'] = array('name'=>'sue smith',
               'email'=>'ss@ss.com',
                  'id'=>'3' );

$users['4'] = array('name'=>'zach zed',
               'email'=>'zz@zz.com',
                  'id'=>'4' );

function sort_jerry_and_sue($users)
{
    $j_and_s=array('jj@jj.com', 'ss@ss.com');
    $not_js=array();
    foreach($j_and_s as $row=>$js){
            if(in_array($js, $users)){
            }
            else {
                array_push($not_js, $users);
            }
    }
    return $not_js;
}

$not_js = array_filter($users, 'sort_jerry_and_sue');

print_r($not_js);
// this is what i'd like it to print=> $not_js = Array ([0] => Array ( [name] => bob barker [email] => bb@bb.com [id] => 1 )    [1] => Array ( [name] => zach zed [email] => zz@zz.com [id] => 4 ))
print_r($js);
// this is what i'd like it to print=> $js = Array ([0] => Array ( [name] => jerry jones [email] => jj@jj.com [id] => 2 ) [1]   => Array ( [name] => sue smith [email] => ss@ss.com [id] => 3 ))
?>
```

Currently printing `$not_js` returns all 4 users and the `$js` doesn't print anything so obviously that's not right. Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are going about this the wrong way.  `array_filter` is like a `array_map` call that takes as its second argument a callable that will return a boolean determining whether or not the value exists in the filtered set.  The argument to the `sort_jerry_and_sue` function will be each user element of the `$users` array, one by one.

By returning false if the user has one of the predefined email addresses, you essentially filer them out of the resultant array.

Once you have one set of a boolean filtered set, you get the compliment by doing an array_diff_assoc to get the difference.

```
<?php


class EmailFilter {

  private $emails = array();

  public function __construct(array $emails) {
    $this->emails = $emails;
  }

  public function filter_users($user) {
    return in_array($user['email'], $this->emails);
  }

}

$users['1'] = array('name'=>'bob barker', 'email'=>'bb@bb.com', 'id'=>'1');
$users['2'] = array('name'=>'jerry jones', 'email'=> 'jj@jj.com', 'id'=>'2' );
$users['3'] = array('name'=>'sue smith', 'email'=>'ss@ss.com', 'id'=>'3' );
$users['4'] = array('name'=>'zach zed', 'email'=>'zz@zz.com', 'id'=>'4' );

$filter_emails = array('jj@jj.com', 'ss@ss.com');
$not_js = array_filter($users, array(new EmailFilter($filter_emails), 'filter_users'));
$js = array_diff_assoc($users, $not_js);

// this is what i'd like it to print=> $not_js = Array ([0] => Array ( [name] => bob barker [email] => bb@bb.com [id] => 1 )    [1] => Array ( [name] => zach zed [email] => zz@zz.com [id] => 4 ))
print_r($not_js);
// this is what i'd like it to print=> $js = Array ([0] => Array ( [name] => jerry jones [email] => jj@jj.com [id] => 2 ) [1]   => Array ( [name] => sue smith [email] => ss@ss.com [id] => 3 ))
print_r($js);
?>
```

Comment: sberry, one more question: how would i take the $j_and_s array outside of the sort_jerry_and_sue() function? I've tried to make it a 2nd parameter alongside $users but that doesn't work, any thoughts? thanks, -tim

Answer (score 0):

Try looping through the `users` array instead of `j_and_s`:

```
function sort_jerry_and_sue($users)
{
    $j_and_s=array('jj@jj.com', 'ss@ss.com');
    $not_js=array();
    foreach($users as $js){
            if(in_array($js['email'], $j_and_s)){
            }
            else {
                array_push($not_js, $users);
            }
    }
    return $not_js;
}
```